# Передача параметра в конструктор базового класса

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование

Проясните ситуацию.
Пытаюсь вызвать конструктор базового класса с параметром из списка инициализации потомка без параметра (сделать его по-умолчанию), но компилятор выдает ошибку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Base
{
    string privateVar;
    
    public:
        Base() = delete;
        Base(string var) : privateVar(move(var)) {}
        ~Base() = default;
        
        string getVar()
        {
            return privateVar;
        }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        //КОМЕНТ// Derived(string var) : Base(var) {}  // <- Так без ошибок
        Derived() : Base("test") {}
        
        ~Derived() = default;
};

int main()
{
    //КОМЕНТ// Derived d("TEST");  // <- Так без ошибок
    Derived d();
    cout << d.getVar();

    return 0;
}
```

Текст ошибки:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:34:15: error: request for member ‘getVar’ in ‘d’, which is of non-class type ‘Derived()’
     cout << d.getVar();
```

Хотя, если предавать через конструктор потомка с параметром, все проходит успешно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот такая запись

```
 Derived d();
```

это не создание объекта, а объявление функции (да да). А у функции нельзя позвать функцию....

Правильно вот так

```
Derived d{};
```

или так

```
Derived d;
```